# 400 bad resquest in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Ajax call looks like this

```js
 function Submit() {
  var objectData =
         {
              email: $("#email").val(),
             firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
             lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
             loginMode: $("#loginMode").val(),
             primaryMobile: $("#primaryMobile").val() 

        };

var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);
    console.log(objectDataString);
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/customer/saveCustomerDetails",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: objectDataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               alert('Success');
               $objectDataString.append('<li>email: '+data.email+', firstName: '+data.firstName+', lastName: '+data.lastName+', loginMode: '+data.loginMode+', primaryMobile: '+data.primaryMobile+ '</li>');

            },
            error: function () {
             alert('Error');
            }
        });
 }
```

and i am getting the error in console look like this:

```
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/customer/saveCustomerDetails [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 123ms]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: **solve this problem as early as possible ??**

Comment: Bad request indicates the server thinks there is something wrong with your request. We need to see your serverside code to help you with that.

Comment: You should really, really reconsider the phrasing of: "Please solve this problem as early as possible.". Stackoverflow is not a code writing service!

Comment: I think that the bad request is here : "please solve this problem as early as possible"

Comment: can any one give the answer for above question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `contentType` of both the request and response match.

Comment: yes  contentType of both the request and response are matched